# Error -swift-Tableview-custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview, cell

I got an error message  that says" Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments" how can I fix it

```
//declaration  of children
var children = [Child]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = children[indexPath.row] //error appears here
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: what is the type of `children`?

Comment: it's an array of type child

Comment: Probably optional, isn't it?. Don't do that. For a table view data source declare the array always as non-optional empty array like `var children = [Child]()`

Comment: sorry , but how can I remove the error

Comment: sorry, you would get better and more satisfying responses if you would provide more detailed information. Is `children` optional? What exactly is `Child`? The text property of `textLabel` expects a type string but assuming `Child` is a custom class, it cannot be a string.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by optional how can I know if it's or not .. child is an class that has attributes as name and image of type string "the content of the cell " each cell of the table view has the name and image of child,, I'm really sorry I'm new to Xcode  ,,thanks for your response

Comment: If you don't know what an optional is, please read the Swift Language Guide. It's indicated with `?` or `!` in the declaration line of a variable. You could update your post by inserting the declaration line of `children`. However declare the variable non optional as I suggested. If you want to display the `name` property, write `children[indexPath.row].name`

Comment: I just try children[indexPath.row].name and the table view appears empty

Comment: But no error any more? That's a progress. Now you have to check where the array `children` is populated and whether the method `numberOfRowsInSection` is implemented properly.

Comment: thanks a lot Vadian ,it works now

Answer (score 0):

`children` is probably not specified as an Array of Strings.  You need to explicitly cast `children[indexPath.row]` to a String, or change the type of `children`

```
cell.textLabel?.text = children[indexPath.row] as! String
```

Comment: how can I cast the array to string

Comment: thanks Andy , but I'm sorry the same error still appears